# Formula field error for checking blank number field

Tags: formula

I am trying to create a text formula field called "Check number of mobiles captured":

```
TEXT(
    IF(
        ISBLANK( Account.No_of_Mobs__c ), 
        "No", 
        "Yes"
    )
)
```

This is a text formula field which checks Account.No_of_Mobs__c (number field) to find out if it is blank.

However i am getting the following error

> Error: Incorrect parameter type for function 'TEXT()'. Expected Number, Date, DateTime, Picklist, received Text

can someone please help on this? much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The result of your `IF()` is either "yes" or "no"

both of those are already of type `Text`, as evidenced by the error you're getting saying that you're trying to pass something of type `Text` to the `TEXT()` function.

Just get rid of the `TEXT()` and keep the stuff inside of it (i.e. keep the entirety of the `IF()`)

Comment: thank you Derek this worked :)